# Easiest way to replace some single quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have the following example string: `'Sam's Place'` and I want to change it to `"Sam's Place"`. Is there an easy way to manipulate a sting with single quotes into using double quotes? The important part is to keep the one single quote in the string.

I have tried:

```
var samsPlaceName = samsPlace.replace(/'/g, '"');

// And:

JSON.stringify(samsPlace);

// Both give me:

'Sam"s Place'

'"Sam's Place"'
```

All I want is to change the string to be: `"Sam's Place"`.

Can this be done?

Comment: So you want to convert `'\'Sam\'s Place\''` to `"\"Sam's Place\""`?

Comment: Assuming the string delimiters are always the first and last characters in your string: `samsPlace.replace(/^'|'$/g, '"')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
// assume you have a string
var samsPlace = "'Sam's Place'";
console.log(samsPlace);

// replace the single quote at the beginning and end of string with double quote by
// using anchors where ^ denotes BOS (beginning of string) and $ denotes EOS (end of 
// string)
console.log(samsPlace.replace(/^'|'$/g, '"'));
```

Comment: Explanation wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: @nem035 Sure. Updating.

Comment: @Psidom accept its not the string you showed its: `'"Sam's Place"'`

Comment: What is your original string? If you have a string like `'Sam\'s Place'`, then you don't need to replace any thing, the single quote at the beginning and end of the string is not part of the string and there's no way to replace as well.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use this?

```
var str = '"Sams place"'
while(str.indexOf('"') != -1){
  str = str.replace('"',"'");
}
```

I hope i don't get you wrong :S

Comment: This is worse, it has to loop over all characters again and again every time it finds a qoute

Comment: This is very inefficient because `indexof` . You can use simple array access instead. `str = '"' + str.substring(1, str.length - 1) + '"'`